# Error of election polls for parliament

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Given a poll, where $N$ people were polled, and $n_i$ people voted for party $i$, so that: $$\sum{n_i} = N$$
If there are M parliament seats in total we can expect: 
$$m_i = M\cdot\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty} (n_i/N)$$
To be the number of parliament seats party $i$ will have.

My question regards the error involved in this prediction:

**What is it's error distribution and what is it's variance?**

If the number of seats were not finite, I'd say that the distribution would be Poisson and each poll value should be $n_i \pm \sqrt{n_i}$, but since the sum is given, It would seem the errors must be correlated in some way.

Any ideas?

Comment: To make things more complicated, the number of seats is usually an integer, which could suggest that the seat allocation method used for fractions could have an effect.

Comment: @Henry - of course. The actual system used in my country is a variant of the [D'Hondt method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D%27Hondt_method), And I wouldn't even try writing the formula down. I just was trying to understand what the actual polling error is, as the papers don't seem to be very keen on explaining what "4.5% error" refers to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the polling population is infinite, the $n_i$ follow a [multinomial distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_distribution). If the population is finite, the $n_i$ follow a [multivariate hypergeometric](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution#Multivariate_hypergeometric_distribution) distribution. The Wikipedia pages have the variances and covariances for both cases.

Comment: Now that I think of it, the multivariate hypergeometric distribution gives me the opposite of what I'm looking for - It gives the chances of getting $n_i$ voters in the poll who will vote $i$ given $N_i$ total $i$ voters. What I'm looking for is the opposite: The chances of there being $N_i$ total voters, given $n_i$ voters in the poll who will vote $i$. How can I "invert" this distribution?